# Getting the last value by condition (postgreSQL)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, aggregation

I came across the following problem - have table with this structure.

| user_id | created_at | permission |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 126 | 2023-11-11 14:58:46.364 | PERMITTED |
| 126 | 2023-11-08 15:40:03.506 | LIMITED |
| 126 | 2023-11-08 15:29:58.621 | PERMITTED |
| 126 | 2023-11-08 14:45:55.548 | PERMITTED |
| 126 | 2023-11-07 15:26:06.464 | PERMITTED |
| 126 | 2023-11-03 15:00:29.546 | PERMITTED |
| 126 | 2023-11-03 13:51:46.037 | PERMITTED |
| 126 | 2023-11-03 13:03:25.021 | PERMITTED |
| 126 | 2023-11-03 11:36:12.790 | PERMITTED |
| 126 | 2023-11-01 14:07:40.995 | PERMITTED |
| 126 | 2023-11-01 11:33:41.212 | PERMITTED |
| 139 | 2023-11-16 12:17:30.313 | LIMITED |
| 139 | 2023-11-16 12:12:04.580 | PERMITTED |
| 139 | 2023-11-09 12:06:11.167 | LIMITED |
| 139 | 2023-11-09 12:05:39.514 | DENIED |
| 139 | 2023-11-09 12:05:33.099 | DENIED |
| 139 | 2023-11-09 12:04:55.336 | DENIED |
| 139 | 2023-11-09 12:03:40.164 | DENIED |
| 139 | 2023-11-09 12:03:19.395 | DENIED |
| 139 | 2023-11-09 12:02:58.150 | DENIED |
| 139 | 2023-11-09 12:02:18.716 | DENIED |
| 139 | 2023-11-09 12:01:56.353 | DENIED |
| 139 | 2023-11-09 12:01:38.890 | DENIED |
| 139 | 2023-11-09 12:01:13.951 | DENIED |
| 139 | 2023-11-09 12:00:59.228 | DENIED |
| 139 | 2023-11-09 12:00:42.786 | DENIED |
| 139 | 2023-11-02 12:05:12.141 | LIMITED |
| 139 | 2023-11-02 12:04:09.914 | DENIED |

My task is to get the latest entry for each user. It should look like this:

| user_id | permission |
| --- | --- |
| 126 | PERMITTED |
| 139 | LIMITED |

I tried to do this with this script:

```
select distinct(user_id), last_value(permission) over (partition by user_id) from public.parking_attempt_statistics
           where user_id in (139, 126)
           order by user_id, created_at desc
```

but take wrong  data in table (**user_id 139** - looks like the most frequently occurring value is taken, not the last one):

| user_id | permission |
| --- | --- |
| 126 | PERMITTED |
| 139 | DENIED |

please tell me where am I wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find solution to redshift -

```
with last_parking_cte as(      
    select user_id, created_at, permission, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
  PARTITION BY user_id order by created_at desc) as rank_ from public.parking_attempt_statistics
           where user_id in (139, 126) and created_at >= '2023-11-01 00:00:00' 
           order by user_id, created_at desc)
           select user_id, permission from last_parking_cte
           where rank_ = 1
```

I can’t say that this is best practice, but works

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CORRELATED SUBQUERY` to achieve this. We return the latest entry in the table for the corresponding `user_id`.

**Schema (PostgreSQL v15)**

```
CREATE TABLE parking_attempt_statistics (
  "user_id" INTEGER,
  "created_at" TIMESTAMP,
  "permission" VARCHAR(9)
);

INSERT INTO parking_attempt_statistics
  ("user_id", "created_at", "permission")
VALUES
  ('126', '2023-11-11 14:58:46.364', 'PERMITTED'),
  ('126', '2023-11-08 15:40:03.506', 'LIMITED'),
  ('126', '2023-11-08 15:29:58.621', 'PERMITTED'),
  ('126', '2023-11-08 14:45:55.548', 'PERMITTED'),
  ('126', '2023-11-07 15:26:06.464', 'PERMITTED'),
  ('126', '2023-11-03 15:00:29.546', 'PERMITTED'),
  ('126', '2023-11-03 13:51:46.037', 'PERMITTED'),
  ('126', '2023-11-03 13:03:25.021', 'PERMITTED'),
  ('126', '2023-11-03 11:36:12.790', 'PERMITTED'),
  ('126', '2023-11-01 14:07:40.995', 'PERMITTED'),
  ('126', '2023-11-01 11:33:41.212', 'PERMITTED'),
  ('139', '2023-11-16 12:17:30.313', 'LIMITED'),
  ('139', '2023-11-16 12:12:04.580', 'PERMITTED'),
  ('139', '2023-11-09 12:06:11.167', 'LIMITED'),
  ('139', '2023-11-09 12:05:39.514', 'DENIED'),
  ('139', '2023-11-09 12:05:33.099', 'DENIED'),
  ('139', '2023-11-09 12:04:55.336', 'DENIED'),
  ('139', '2023-11-09 12:03:40.164', 'DENIED'),
  ('139', '2023-11-09 12:03:19.395', 'DENIED'),
  ('139', '2023-11-09 12:02:58.150', 'DENIED'),
  ('139', '2023-11-09 12:02:18.716', 'DENIED'),
  ('139', '2023-11-09 12:01:56.353', 'DENIED'),
  ('139', '2023-11-09 12:01:38.890', 'DENIED'),
  ('139', '2023-11-09 12:01:13.951', 'DENIED'),
  ('139', '2023-11-09 12:00:59.228', 'DENIED'),
  ('139', '2023-11-09 12:00:42.786', 'DENIED'),
  ('139', '2023-11-02 12:05:12.141', 'LIMITED'),
  ('139', '2023-11-02 12:04:09.914', 'DENIED');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT a.user_id, a.created_at, a.permission
FROM parking_attempt_statistics a
WHERE a.created_at =
    (SELECT MAX(created_at)
     FROM parking_attempt_statistics
     WHERE user_id = a.user_id);
```

| user_id | created_at | permission |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 126 | 2023-11-11T14:58:46.364Z | PERMITTED |
| 139 | 2023-11-16T12:17:30.313Z | LIMITED |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct
    user_id,
    first_value(permission) over (
        partition by user_id order by created_at desc) as last_permission
from public.parking_attempt_statistics
where user_id in (139, 126)
order by user_id;
```

You could also specify the window frame:

```
last_value(permission) over (
    partition by user_id order by created_at
    rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)
```